# React Native Scrollview keyboardshouldpersisttaps not working for ios

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, scrollview

I have a Login screen where I wrap the entire component with ScrollView and apply keyboardshouldpersisttaps prop as always. The prop seems to work fine on android but not on ios, on tapping the textInput, it gets hidden under keyboard.

Below is my code for the login screen

```
  <View>
        <ScrollView
          style={styles.scrollviewStyle}
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
          <View style={styles.topContainerStyle}>
            <View style={styles.padding}>
              <Text style={styles.skipTextStyle}>SKIP</Text>
              <Image source={BlackLogo} style={styles.logoStyle} />
            </View>
          </View>
          <Image source={PreLoginImage} style={styles.preLoginImageStyle} />
          <View style={styles.padding}>
            <Text style={styles.getStartedTextStyle}>Let's Get started</Text>

              <View style={styles.bottomContainer}>
                <TextInput
                  // onChangeText={mobile => this.onMobileEnter(mobile)}
                  style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
                  value={this.state.mobile}
                  maxLength={10}
                  onCodeChange={this.onCodeChange}
                />

                <TouchableHighlight
                  disabled={!this.state.mobile ? true : false}
                  onPress={() => this.onProceedPress()}
                  style={
                    !this.state.mobile
                      ? styles.disabledContinueButtonStyles
                      : styles.continueButtonStyles
                  }>
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      alignSelf: 'center',
                      fontFamily: 'Roboto-Medium',
                      fontSize: 16,
                      marginTop: 18,
                      color: '#FFFFFF',
                    }}>
                    CONTINUE
                  </Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
              </View>

            <Text style={styles.termsStyle}>
              By continuing, you agree to Remedico's terms of use and privacy
              Policy.
            </Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  topContainerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#F4EBE4',
    height: deviceHeight * 0.4,
  },
  logoStyle: {
    width: 139,
    height: 45,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    top: 123,
  },
  padding: {
    padding: 24,
  },
  preLoginImageStyle: {
    width: 178,
    height: 167,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: deviceHeight * 0.2,
    left: deviceWidth * 0.5,
  },
  getStartedTextStyle: {
    paddingTop: 60,
    fontFamily: 'Ubuntu-Medium',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  skipTextStyle: {
    left: deviceWidth - 80,
    fontFamily: 'Roboto-Medium',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  bottomContainer: {
    paddingTop: 32,
  },
  continueButtonStyles: {
    marginTop: 84.5,
    borderRadius: 25,
    backgroundColor: '#00ACC1',
    height: 55,
  },
  disabledContinueButtonStyles: {
    marginTop: 84.5,
    borderRadius: 25,
    backgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
    height: 55,
  },
  termsStyle: {
    fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular',
    fontSize: 12,
    paddingTop: 32,
    color: '#808080',
  },
  scrollviewStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    height: deviceHeight,
  },
  // activityIndicatorStyle:{
  //    marginTop: 84.5
  // },
});
```

[image: before tapping the textinput]

[image: upon tapping on textInput,it gets hidden under keyboard and the screen is also not scrollable.]

Please do suggest why is it so, and how will it be working on ios, any suggestion would be a help,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `keyboardshouldpersisttaps` props of `ScrollView` will solve your problem. This props will only dismiss the keyboard when you press on the container view.

Please check ref: https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#keyboardshouldpersisttaps

I suggest you to use https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view for your problem.

Hope that help. :)

Comment: This did work but could you suggest on ScrollView, I mean why is this performance issue occuring on IOS and what is the way out for this?

Comment: Hi @TRINACHAUDHURI, as I answer earlier, this issue is not related to `keyboardshouldpersisttaps`. And about why this only occurring on IOS, because in Android, their is a property `android:windowSoftInputMode` in `AndroidManifest.xml` will resize the screen to make room for the softkeyboard, so in some case, it will look like "avoiding" input, but it not always true.

Comment: And about the solution for your issue, highly recommend to use the `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view ` library, you can find more about it on their github. :)

Comment: @BrianH. I don't see any reference to avoiding double taps in their issues or doc. Can you point me to the issue/doc where it is being discussed?